# a static issue with asp.net multiple users/clients

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, session, client-side

is it safe to use static in asp.net ?

the situation is this :

counter in code behind is reporting back to user on each forLoop

so:

```
<div id="report"></div>
```

will be set via jquery ajax thats because if i will add `runat="Server"`
it will not be displayed till all iterations will take place.

so using jquery to triger a `[Webmethod]` is the only way i could come up with to update content of the div while running

so the question is if 10 users will simultaneously trigger the webmethod

```
static int result=someStaticMethodRandomOutput();
[webmethod]
static void StatMet(object userInput){
    return result + intValue() * Convert.ToInt32(userInput);
}

static int intValue(){
   static int someCalculation=someOtherStaticValFromOtherMethodToReturn;
   return someClaculation;
}
```

and in client side the jQueryAjax will show values returned...

now is it true that returned value or result value or some of values here will be shared by all or some of the users ?

Comment: C# does not support static local variables.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods must be `static`. I think it is safe (pun intended) to say that there is never anything safe when dealing with `static`, especially `static` fields.

Comment: (removed "a"; apparently this type of method must indeed be `static`) , b: even if it were true, that doesn't make it "safe", and c: there's a difference between static *methods* and static *fields* - static *fields* are most certainly ***not*** safe in asp.net

Comment: You are misunderstanding the context here, ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods are different than just a method in the ASP.NET Page class. The `[WebMethod]` attribute on the method is what ASP.NET AJAX is using to treat it as script invokable. I have updated my original answer to include the word AJAX. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm familiar with `[WebMethod]`  but I've *never* seen it used with `static`, or seen any restriction that it must be used with `static` - can you be more specific, perhaps with some citation?

Comment: [Why do ASP.NET AJAX page methods have to be static?](http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/)

Comment: is it true , cause as far as i remember(and i remember it does have to) trying with and without static does matter, i will test to see if it "connects" to the method with and without `static` just to make sure ajax is triggering it in relation to modifier or not

Comment: I think part of the problem is that most people associate the `[WebMethod]` with XML Web Services (.asmx) and that restriction certainly does not exist there.

Comment: @karl that's ... very interesting; fair enough - if this is a *different* `[WebMethod]` usage, then I have learned something new and curious. But: that still doesn't make them automatically "safe" - you need to be ***really*** careful if touching static state such as fields

Comment: @MarcGravell - I should have been more explicit in my answer. Thanks for keeping me honest. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`result` is a static field, and is indeed shared between all calls - which means the results at runtime could be **very** unreliable in a multi-threaded environment like asp.net; although saying that, it is initialized  in a field initializer and doesn't *seem* to be changed, so you'll probably get away with it. If it can't change, add `readonly` to make this obvious; if it *can* change, it is a huge problem.

`someCalculation` doesn't make sense - there is no such thing as a `static` local variable in C#, and it won't compile.

Comment: ok first, nice to know that with Webmethod **it's not a must** to use a `static` modifier. second i will post a new code when i will convert my program so the result div will be updated via Ajax post/call from javascript trigger, as opposed to first try(`resDiv.InnerText=value;` which will show only at the end of request) so now i'll try the next option for output 'current' State via client side "triggering system"

Comment: @AviaAfer well, karl seems to disagree with me on that - I don't claim to be infallible, but I am certainly not aware of any such restriction; however, static or non-static: that doesn't change how any static *fields* would behave

Comment: ok i am sorry to jump start this post for nothing with reason or not whell structured. i will come back to check on my real scenario which will be much clearer and colser to day by day use(till now, most of my simple c# WebApps just sent a request for some processing data and return when finished, i am moving to little more complex when page needed to be updated while in action)